# Node Express Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am currently writing an express app and want to use some custom middleware that I have written however express keeps throwing an issue.

I have an `es6` class that has a method that accepts the correct parameters like below:

```js
foo(req, res, next){
   console.log('here');
}
```

then in my app I am telling express to use it like so:

```js
const module = require('moduleName');
...
app.use(module.foo);
```

but express keeps throwing this error:

```
app.use() requires middleware functions
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `foo(req, res, next){
   console.log('here');
}` ?

Answer (score 1):

This error always occurs `TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions`

Since you are not exporting that function that's why it's unreachable

try to export it like this from file

```
exports.foo=function(req, res, next){
   console.log('here');
   next();
}
```

You can also use `module.exports`

```
module.exports={
  foo:function(req,res,next){
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but then I lose access to the class methods. Is there not a way to use class methods as middleware?

Comment: you can take a look here how to access class method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782453/class-methods-in-node-js

Comment: The class code is similar to this, (sorry can't show the exact code as it's for a clients application). http://pastebin.com/dTdseg3L where bar would be the method I want to use as middleware

Comment: no one can guess what exactly happening with you until see your code

Answer (score 1):

The solution has two parts. First make the middleware function a static method of that class that you export from your module. This function needs to take an instance of your class and will invoke whatever methods you need to.

```
"use strict";

class Middle {
  constructor(message) {
    this._message = message;
  }

  static middleware(middle) {

    return function middleHandler(req, res, next) {
      // this code is invoked on every request to the app

      // start request processing and perhaps stop now.
      middle.onStart(req, res);

      // let the next middleware process the request
      next();
    };
  }

  // instance methods
  onStart(req, res) {
    console.log("Middleware was given this data on construction ", this._message);
  }
}

module.exports = Middle;
```

Then in your node JS / express app server, after requiring the module, create an instance of your class. Then pass this instance into the middleware function.

```
var Middle = require('./middle');
var middle = new Middle("Sample data for middle to use");
app.use(Middle.middleware(middle));
```

Now on every request your middle ware runs with access to the class data.